How to alter this meta query for elementor custom query so it includes if a checkbox in post IS checked
At the time of trying to build a custom query for a sports website which includes the latest result score showing in a loop grip. The below code works for showing posts that are equal to or past today's date which is OK. But it is required to only show if a ACF custom field check box called show_result is checked in that specific post.
So basically if the "show_result" checkbox is ticked for that post in the back end then the loop grid in Elementor will only show the past posts with this checkbox checked.
Is it possible to modify the code below to include the above conditions?
add_action('elementor/query/latest_result', function($query){ 
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');
    $meta_query[] = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key' => 'match_date',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ],
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
});

Tried varying code with nothing working.

Another array is required in your meta query to address if checkbox is marked (value will be 1).
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'match_date',
        'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'show_result',
        'value' => '1', 
        'compare' => '=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'

    )
);

Now other part of the code should handle this meta query.

Unfortunately when I have tried to add your code to the code snippet I had it hasn’t worked? The loop is disappearing when putting the query name in the element or loop grid query id box

You may have issue with handling $meta_query array.

Thanks for your reply, how would i go about finding that out? I have tried all different variations of code with nothing working?

Focus on array handling
